# Sequilize query is returning only one row while using include

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, select, sequelize.js

**Context :** I am having this problem were I am doing a query using sequilize an it only return's me an array with one position even though I have more than one field that correspond to the query.

**This are my two involved models**

This is my **group.js** model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Group = sequelize.define('Group', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        limit: DataTypes.STRING,
        user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    Group.associate = models => {
        Group.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
    };

    Group.associate = models => {
        Group.hasMany(models.Movement, { foreignKey: 'group_id' });
    };

    return Group;
}
```

This is my **movement.js** model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Mov = sequelize.define('Movement', {
        description: DataTypes.STRING,
        value: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        group_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    });

    Mov.associate = models => {
        Mov.hasOne(models.Group, { foreignKey: 'group_id' });
    };

    return Mov;
}
```

This is my **query** (where you will see that I am doing an `INNER JOIN` to `SUM` the fields of the **Movement** table)

```
router.get('/', verify, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const group = await Group.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'name',
                'limit',
                [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('Movements.value')), 'total_spent'],
            ],
            include: [{
                attributes: [], // this is empty because I want to hide the Movement object in this query (if I want to show the object just remove this)
                model: Movement,
                required: true
            }],
            where: {
                user_id: req.userId
            }
        });
        if (group.length === 0) return res.status(400).json({ error: "This user has no groups" })
        res.status(200).json({ groups: group }) //TODO see why this is onyl return one row
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json({ Error: "Error while fetching the groups" });
    }
});
```

**Problem** is that it only return's one position of the expected array :

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "rgrgrg",
            "limit": 3454354,
            "total_spent": "2533"
        }
    ]
}
```

It **should** return 2 positions

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "rgrgrg",
            "limit": 3454354,
            "total_spent": "2533"
        },
    {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "rgrgrg",
            "limit": 3454354,
            "total_spent": "2533"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the query sequilize is giving me:

```
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`limit`, SUM(`Movements`.`value`) AS `total_spent` FROM `Groups` AS `Group` INNER JOIN `Movements` AS `Movements` ON `Group`.`id` = `Movements`.`group_id` WHERE `Group`.`user_id` = 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure, do you have multiple datas in the group table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to add an appropriate group by clause as follows -

```
const group = await Group.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'limit',
        [sequelize.fn('SUM', sequelize.col('Movements.value')), 'total_spent'],
    ],
    include: [{
        attributes: [], // this is empty because I want to hide the Movement object in this query (if I want to show the object just remove this)
        model: Movement,
        required: true
    }],
    where: {
        user_id: req.userId
    },
    group: '`Movements`.`group_id`'
});
```

Comment: it did not worked. At some point I did this : SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')); because I had an error. Can this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: I think you have not posted your Sequelize statement correctly. In the Sequelize statement mentioned in the question, there is no group by clause. Can you please check and post the sequelize statement with group by clause?

Comment: Yes there is not, and I still have this error on the database? That's the strange part, I had to put this in order to query the database

Comment: Can you please share the query that you want to generate and the query that Sequelize is generating?

Comment: just updated the question with the query sequilize is giving me, it's the query I want, The problem is that is only returning one row and it should return more

Comment: I guess you need to add an appropriate group by clause and I guess in your case it is  `group: '\`Movements\`.\`group_id\`' `

Comment: yes that worked. Please put that in your answer(and remove the raw:true) and I will approve it. Thanks

Comment: @JoséNobre, Welcome, Glad to know that your issue is fixed. As you suggested I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many "through" table with multiple rows of identical foreign key pairs only returns one result?

I just ran into this bug and added this options to the main query:

```
{
  raw: true,
  plain: false, 
  nest: true
}
```

Then you just merge the query.

It's a workaround, but might help someone.

Comment: It did not work for me. Unsetting these properties fixed the issue though. I was expecting an array, even if it had just one object.